# iis 8 mvc.net/extensionless-url windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, iis-8

I haven't seen this specific question...at any rate, I've inherited a server configured by someone who had never touched IIS before (and I heavily suspect this is the root cause...)

At any rate, I have developed 3 different MVC.NET applications and tested them successfully on IIS 7.5 (my dev machine).

One of the sites went into the IIS 8 box using windows auth and had no problems.  In fact, I switch the site to and from windows auth without any issues.

The other two sites would only work if I turned authentication to anonymous.  Otherwise, with windows auth, the extensionless urls all produced 403 error pages.  (By contrast, I could hit .htm and .js files while in windows auth.)

To be clear, I've tried with and without `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` and trick for removing and adding the handler `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`.  I also tried using the `Authorize` attribute to see if it could do something my web.config somehow could not.

So, after a day of permutations on searches and configurations, my best guess is that the 403 I'm experiencing is windows auth related extensionless urls (one of the things I like about MVC.NET).

That said, anyone know how to get past the 403 in IIs 8 and still keep windows auth?

Comment: if it works for one site but not the others, shouldn't the problem be with the configuration of those two rather than the web server? What is the sub status code for the 403s?

Comment: The only issue I find with the configuration of the site theory is that there is nothing in the web.config that stands out as missing or different.   As for the sub status code, I'm not being given one that fiddler can see.